# Ajax code for input fields to act like Gmail's to Field

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm interested in coding an input field to behave as the 'to' field in gmail's compose screen. Meaning that each data is encapsulated with a frame which has an 'x' option to remove it.

[image: gmail to field]

Comment: Google "jquery tags plugin"

Comment: I see that are several ones, which one do you recommend ?

Comment: I haven't used any, I just know they exist.

Comment: Hate it when a good question is closed!!!

Comment: Here's another good option: [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Answer (score 4):

Search for javascript tag plugins. If you can use jQuery, I recommend [jQuery Tagit](http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/) plugin. Very customizable and easy to use.